# How to filter a specific item from an array in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-model

here is my controller :

```
   varDemoApp.controller('SimpleController',function($scope){
        $scope.customers = [{name:'Ahsan',city:'Khulna'},
            {name:'Rokib',city:'Bogra'},
            {name:'Asad',city:'Satkhira'}];

    });
```

And my html code is :

```
<div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    Name:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="name"/>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers|filter:name|orderBy:'name'">
            {{cust.city}}-{{cust.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to filtered only by 'customers.name' but now it filter by overall customers array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass an object into filter expression:

```
filter:{name:name}
```

Comment: @artem if more than one filter is needed then how will the expression go?
will it be `filter:[{name:name},{city:city}]`? I am just a newbie to angular reached here googling